# MagicalImport only working for new entities

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I got the following code:

```
SPKMatch *match = [SPKMatch MR_createInContext:localContext];
[match MR_importValuesForKeysWithObject:record];
```

It works fine. But actually I want to update the entities already existing instead of create always a new one. That should be done with the following:

```
    [SPKMatch MR_importFromObject:record inContext:localContext];
```

But that crashes. What to do?

Comment: Can you please post more code? Is `record` nil? We can't really see what's going on in this context.

Comment: I am getting the same problem. Basically MR_importFromObject is working only for inserting an object which doesn't exist already. If you call this function with an object which already exists, it throws an error.

Comment: have you solve it this problem I need to update entity as well